# MySQL workbench cannot connect to server (MacOS Ventura)?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I downloaded MySQL and MySQL workbench on MacOS about a week ago to learn SQL. I was able to use it perfectly the first time I downloaded it. However, I restarted the workbench app and now I'm unable to connect to the server. I get the error "Cannot connect to localhost".

I've tried reinstalling both MySQL and MySQL workbench but I'm still unable to connect to the server. I've also tried stopping the MySQL server in my systems settings and initializing the database but I also keep getting the error "Failed to initialize the database". I'm at a total loss as to what to do.

Comment: "*I also keep getting the error "Failed to initialize the database".*" Can you provide the relevant context of the output from which you're seeing this message? How exactly are you stopping/starting the MySQL service? From where did you download and install MySQL and the MySQL Workbench client?

Comment: The context is that I saw a solution to my problem online by initializing the database through the MySQL panel in my system settings. I'm stopping it in the MySQL panel in my system settings. I downloaded MySQL and Workbench from the MySQL website and installed both in my /Users/myname/Downloads. I don't think the installation is the issue as it was working before.

Comment: Sorry, my ask was for any log lines from the file or view in which you're seeing the message "*Failed to initialize the database*". They should contain information pertinent to discovering the root cause of the failure you're describing.